# Encounters, interactions, and great losses

Tags: neuroscience, social-psychology, memory, brain-training, social-cognition

When you encounter someone and interact with someone, it forms a pattern in the brain (and the brain stores, stuff, in some way).

When something goes missing, then something in your mind can't be reached, and it came be reached by the heart, and the system of emotions, that spreads throughout the body.

So what is needed for metal health and well being, in the mind of someone who potentially could undergo great loses.

Thank you.